# Aggregate rows based on there column values pandas

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have data in this format:

```
Company     Region  Category    Metric    Year  Month   Value
Industry    Total   NARTD   Sales Value   2017  Jan     1.448129e+09
Industry    Total   NARTD   Sales Volume  2017  Jan     3.573664e+08
Industry    Total   NARTD   Sales Value   2018  Jan     1.422279e+09
Industry    Total   NARTD   Sales Volume  2018  Jan     3.492432e+08
```

And I want to Add another column at the end with sales value / sales volume for each row with other columns data same, except Year. Aggregation need to be done for same year same year sales value and volume.

output:

```
Company     Region  Category    Metric    Year  Month   Value         AVG
Industry    Total   NARTD   Sales Value   2017  Jan     1.448129e+09  Sal.val(2017)/Sal.Vol(2017)
Industry    Total   NARTD   Sales Volume  2017  Jan     3.573664e+08  Sal.val(2017)/Sal.Vol(2017)
Industry    Total   NARTD   Sales Value   2018  Jan     1.422279e+09  Sal.val(2018)/Sal.Vol(2018)
Industry    Total   NARTD   Sales Volume  2018  Jan     3.492432e+08  Sal.val(2018)/Sal.Vol(2018)
```

Case

```
Region  Category    Company     Metric      Year    Month   Value
Convenience     NARTD   TCC     Sales Value 2018    Dec     NaN
Traditional     NARTD   TCC     Sales Value 2018    Dec     NaN
Total           NARTD   TCC     Sales Value 2018    Dec     NaN
Hyper/Super     NARTD   TCC     Sales Value 2018    Dec     NaN
```

Comment: Can you add expected output? Be free change data to sample like `10,20` ...

Comment: Can you post you code which you have tried so far.

Comment: @has am trying to do pivot_table and calculating pivoted_df = pd.pivot_table(df, index = ['Region', 'Category', 'Company','Year','Month'], columns = 'Metric').reset_index().rename_axis  not good at pivot things

Comment: @jezrael Post updated. Please check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC, it's easiest to pivot first to have all the values per year on a single row, then do the divide, and then melt to reshape to the original frame:

```
piv = df.pivot_table(index=['Company', 'Region', 'Category', 
              'Year', 'Month'], columns=['Metric'], values='Value').reset_index()
piv['AVG'] = piv['SalesValue'] / piv['SalesVolume']

piv.melt(id_vars=['Company', 'Region', 'Category', 
              'Year', 'Month', 'AVG'])

#     Company Region Category      ...            AVG       Metric         value
# 0  Industry  Total    NARTD      ...       4.052225   SalesValue  1.448129e+09
# 1  Industry  Total    NARTD      ...       4.072460   SalesValue  1.422279e+09
# 2  Industry  Total    NARTD      ...       4.052225  SalesVolume  3.573664e+08
# 3  Industry  Total    NARTD      ...       4.072460  SalesVolume  3.492432e+08
```

Comment: Thank you. Works Fine. I have some data Year: 2018 and Month Dec (in same data file) Which have Sales Value and Sales Volume "None" . While Doing this I see its deleting those data. At pivoting step.

Comment: I added the data to the question (initially I shared a part of the data). When applying the pivot Table it removing those kind of data (Data With Sales Value & Sales Volume ~ NaN ~ None).

Comment: And what would be your desired output for those rows?

Comment: I want to keep those rows data and Value as 'None'. Any reason am missing those data??

Comment: I see we have an argument in pivot_table "dropna" with default value True, Made it False. And Got the result. Thank you.